Calculating work from home expenses
I'm self-employed freelancer, and primarily work from home. I work more than 101 hours per month from home. I'm trying to calculate the proportion of my home expenses (energy bills, council tax, mortgage interest) that I can use as tax relief.
Using the simplified expenses route (£26 per month), while simple, the amount of £312 per year is lower than calculating the actual expenses.
How does calculating the actual expenses work in practice? My home has 4 bedrooms and 1 living room. I use one of the rooms as my office exclusively for my freelancing. This means I use up energy and broadband from that room.
So if my energy bill for the year was let's say £1000, does that mean I can claim £200 (1000/5) as expenses? Or is it £250 (1000/4), counting only the 4 bedrooms? Is it as simple as dividing the total amount by number of rooms, or do I need to do something more complicated such as calculating the office dimensions as a percentage of the full house size?
Using 20% of my home expenses allows me to claim more than using the simplified route, but I'm not sure if it's simply calculating the 20% in my case, or if there is more to it.
I also assume I can claim tax relief on proportion of the council tax and mortgage interest, based on whatever percentage my office is meant to take (by dimension or by number of rooms).

The examples at https://www.gov.uk/hmrc-internal-manuals/business-income-manual/bim47825 might be helpful.  And there will surely be other relevant stuff in https://www.gov.uk/hmrc-internal-manuals/business-income-manual/bim47800
